# Почему сетка bootstrap 3 криво работает

Tags: bootstrap

Помогите разобраться с сеткой бутстрапа. Почему то в col-md-4 и col-lg-4 крайняя колонка спускается вниз! Почему?
 К примеру:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

   <div class="seriesBlock col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" >
       какая-то инфа
    </div>
<div class="seriesBlock col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" >
       какая-то инфа
    </div>
<div class="seriesBlock col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" >
       какая-то инфа
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ну добавьте пример сниппетом или на jsfiddle, или еще где нить. отступы не перекрывали ни где в стилях?

Comment: В самой сетке всё нормально, скорее всего может у Вас что-то в классе seriesBlock написано, что и заставляет блок переходить на низ

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, у меня на md и lg ничего не опускается - только на sm, но оно и понятно, ведь там col-sm-6:

```css
.col-xs-12 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

   <div class="seriesBlock col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" >
       какая-то инфа
    </div>
<div class="seriesBlock col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" >
       какая-то инфа
    </div>
<div class="seriesBlock col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" >
       какая-то инфа
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```